# 3.10 kernel crash BUG() in mark_bootmem()

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, device-tree

I get a kernel crash at BUG() here - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/bootmem.c?v=3.10#L385 with the following message

```
2kernel BUG at /kernel/mm/bootmem.c:385!
```

What could be a possible reason for this?

Following is the function call trace

```
[<c0e165f8>] (mark_bootmem+0xd0/0xe0) from [<c0e05d64>] (bootmem_init+0x16c/0x26
[<c0e05d64>] (bootmem_init+0x16c/0x264) from [<c0e07980>] (paging_init+0x734/0x7
[<c0e07980>] (paging_init+0x734/0x7d4) from [<c0e03f20>] (setup_arch+0x3e8/0x69c
[<c0e03f20>] (setup_arch+0x3e8/0x69c) from [<c0e007d8>] (start_kernel+0x78/0x370
[<c0e007d8>] (start_kernel+0x78/0x370) from [<10008074>] (0x10008074)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you modified the kernel code in any way or is this a result of an upgrade or something? If you have not changed the kernel code this isn't really an appropriate question as we're not going to attempt to debug a specific kernel version on your machine.

Comment: Add something like `memory { reg = <0x80000000 0x8000000>; };`, where you have a physical address and size.  *u-boot*, etc mess with this to set it to a *probed* size (and/or via traditional u-boot variables).

Answer (score 2):

The `mm/bootmem.c` file is responsible for `Boot Memory Allocator`. Function `mark_bootmem` marks memory pages between `start` and `end` addresses (`start` is rounded down and `end` is rounded up to page boundaries) as reserved (or not reserved when used for freeing) for this allocator.

It iterates over `bdata_list` trying to find a region containing first page from requested address range. It it won't find it, the `BUG()` you mentioned will be triggered. The same `BUG()` will be triggered if it succeeds finding it, but the region is not large enough (`end` is outside of the region). So this `BUG()` means that it wasn't able to find requested memory region to mark.

Now if I understand the kernel code correctly, on normal UMA systems there will be only one entry in `bdata_list` and it should describe the range of lowmemory pages available in the system. Since you didn't provide too much information about your system it's hard to guess exact reason for the problem but in general, it seems that your memory setup is broken. This thing is very architecture specific so it's hard to tell what exactly is going on.